# Legend overlap with plot in base r

Tags: r

Hi I'm trying to get the legend to not overlap with my plot but the solutions I've found on stackoverflow don't seem to be working right now, using the following random data

```
par(mar = c(3,1,1,1))
plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch=1, lty=1, type="o", ylim=c(-2,2))
legend("bottom", legend = c("a","b"), horiz=T,
       bty = "n", pch=15 , col= c("green","red"), text.col = "black", 
       cex=1, pt.cex=1,xpd=T)
```

So this graph has the legend overlapping with the graph even though I have the `xpd = T` argument and I also tried putting in the `inset=c(0,-0.5)` argument but the legend then disappears (can't even see it) so I was wondering what is wrong with the code and how to get the legend to not overlap, thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to add `par(xpd=TRUE)` to enable to drawn outside the graph and add "bottom" for x and an inset. You can use the following code:

```r
par(mar = c(3,1,1,1))
plot(1:3, rnorm(3), pch=1, lty=1, type="o", ylim=c(-2,2))
par(xpd = TRUE)
legend(x="bottom", inset=-0.15, legend = c("a","b"), horiz=T,
       bty = "n", pch=15 , col= c("green","red"), text.col = "black", 
       cex=1, pt.cex=1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Also want to ask if I have three labels in the legend how do I adjust the spacing in between legends such that they are more equal spacing since now the first two are much closer and the third one is to the far right? Thanks!

Comment: Try `x.intersp = 0.2` in your legend. This should move your legend labels closer to each other. Default = 1.